# Neuro-fuzzy system

Tags: java, neural-network, fuzzy-logic

I am looking for software/tool in java which implements the neuro-fuzzy system. I spent a little time in googling around and found encog, neuroph for neural networks in Java. But I need something which does both neural and fuzzy logic, may be like the one (Anfis) which matlab does.

Comment: Neuroph appears to have used a combination of Neural Networks and Fuzzy Logic as outlined in [this paper](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/Neuro%20Fuzzy%20reasoner%20for%20student%20modeling.pdf).  Would this meet your needs for neuro-fuzzy modelling?